# Where was it established that Super Goof's goobers were irradiated by a meteor?

Tags: comics, disney

In old comics from the 1960s and later, Goofy used to have a superhero alter ego, Super Goof. Toonopedia explains that Disney made a trial run in Donald Duck #102 (October 1965), where Gyro Gearloose invented a super cape that Goofy used. The character was well received and

> That same month, he got his own title, and *Super Goof* #1 (also by Connell and Murry) provided yet another origin story. This one involved a goober patch in Goofy's back yard, which, irradiated by a nearby meteorite, yielded super goobers which powered him up when ingested.

I am a bit confused about the line concerning the goobers' connection to a meteor. It has been referenced in many places and even showed up in an episode of Disney's House of Mouse. It is well known that Goofy got his powers from peanuts, or goobers as he calls them, but there does not seem to be any reliable source that shows where in the comics they attribute it to a meteor.

The first issue of the comic, Super Goof #1 (1965), says nothing about it; it only mentions that Goofy managed to grow the goobers in his garden but makes no mention of why they were so special.

[image: Goofy makes a discovery]
[image: The only explanation]

Much later, in Super Goof #31 (1974), the goobers were destroyed by the Beagle Boys, which forced Goofy to seek replacements. His research into the origin of the peanuts led him to a Mexican superhero called Super Señor, who had 'superior goobers' on his ranch and who provided Goofy with new ones.

[image: Super Senor]

That seems to be all the origin there is for the goobers, so where does the meteor come in? Could anyone bring clarity to this?

Comment: What is the source of your quote? If it is a user edited wiki, it might just be a mistake in the entry.

Comment: @Skooba The quote comes from Don Marksteins Toonopedia, but it has been referred to in other places too, like House of Mouse. https://www.toonopedia.com/suprgoof.htm . I see now that they have updated the post slightly and mention Super Señor. There are still claims about meteors though so the question still stands, where that origin comes from.

Answer (score 5):

I do not recall encountering an references to radiation from a meteor being responsible for Goofy's Super Goobers.  However, in [*Super Goof* issue seven](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Super-Goof/Issue-7), Gyro Gearloose demonstrates that he can create new Super Goobers using just his "atomic greenhouse," so nuclear radiation does appear to be the culprit.  (Goofy does not provide Gyro with a Super Goober to work from; he just tells him what is needed in a letter.)

[image: Page 28]

Comment: This is a good find, but even though it explains some about how the goobers work it does not explain why it was attributed to a meteor.